# Trouble with magento's SOAP V2

Tags: c#, magento, soap

I'm trying to connect to magentos web services using c#. I created a role and then created a user with that role. After that, I created the web service references and when trying to connect to the web services, I get the next error:

```
WebException was unhandled
HTTP 401: Unauthorized.
```

What could it be? here's the c# code im using, that displays the result of the login in a label:

```
MagentoService ms = new MagentoService();

        String mlogin = ms.login("testUser", "xxxxxx");


        label1.Text=mlogin;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like your test user is unauthorized.  Perhaps you should add that user to the list of authorized users, or use an authorized user.

Comment: Well the user is added to the Magento server and has all the due roles necesary.

Comment: This may seem silly, but which section of the Magento admin did you use to setup the user?

Comment: I'm creating them from System > Web Services > and then roles and users.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I'm constantly setting up regular admin users when I mean to setup web users, but it looks like you're doing it from the right place.

Comment: Mate which web service are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Magento's Web service.